# How to permanently mount ntfs drive in WUBI installation mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, mount, fstab

I have a Windows 7 installed as my primary operating system on my C:\ drive. I have another ntfs partition, D:.

Ubuntu is installed using WUBI on C:\Ubuntu, which makes C:\ accessible through "/host". D:\ is mounted and can be reached via /media/some-hash, so each time I restart my machine, D:\ gets a different hashed-like name. This whole arrangement causes problems when I try to make links to files and folders located in D:\, which turn useless after each restart.

I know I need to mount D:\ drive permanently, somehow, by editing /etc/fstab. But I couldn't manage to figure out how exactly should I do that.

Any specific and friendly help for noobs would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's really *strange* that the "hash" would change. By default, it's either `/media/drive-label` or `/media/drive-uuid` (if no label), both of which are stored on the drive itself. If you run `lsblk -f` or `sudo blkid`, do they report the same "hash", and does it change across reboots?

Comment: It's strange, I have just rebooted and the "hash" stayed the same as you claimed. Don't know if it has something to do with the fact that It's a fresh installation, but I've been using wubi for a while now, and I know for certain that links to the drive that is not the host for Ubuntu become useless from time to time. I don't know exactly if it's rebooting that does that. It was an assumption based on the only thing I made that could have made a difference (that I noticed).

Comment: NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
loop0               /
sda                 
├─sda1              /host
├─sda2              
└─sda5              /media/2C545B29545AF4D4
sr0

Comment: UUIDs are usually added with the specific purpose of always being the same; a drive's UUID should change only when the drive is reformatted.

Comment: After reading about UUID, it makes sense since UUID starts with "Unique"... don't know, I was quite sure it changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *fstab* syntax is fairly simple:

```
device mountpoint fstype options dump pass
```

- `device` is the device name, which can be made from information displayed in `lsblk -f` or `sudo blkid` commands:

  - `LABEL=foo` or `/dev/disk/by-label/foo` to select by the label (which can be changed in Windows by opening Computer and simply renaming the disk).
  - `UUID=foo` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/foo` to select by the filesystem's unique ID (for NTFS it looks like a 16-letter "hash"). Normally, the UUID **never** changes.
  - `/dev/sdXY` (e.g. `/dev/sda4`) to select by Linux device name, which can sometimes change
- `mountpoint` is the directory, such as "`/media/Windows-D`" or "`/d:`". If it doesn't exist, you need to create it yourself.
- `fstype` is the word "`ntfs`"
- `options` is the word "`defaults`"
- both `dump` and `pass` should be set to "`0`"

So it should look like this:

```
UUID=2C545B29545AF4D4  /media/Data  ntfs  defaults  0  0
```

Or, if you label the drive as `Data disk` in Windows...

```
LABEL=Data\040disk  /media/Data  ntfs  defaults  0  0
```

Comment: Surprisingly I did labeled the drive as "Data"... but I didn't get any indication for that name when I used lsblk -f and sudo blkid. Thanks for the explanation anyway. But if I do that, won't at create a duplicate?